# Share the DVB card on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, lan, dvb-t

I have 2 computers connected to a router and I have a DVB card in one of them. I want to use the one DVB card to feed both of them.

I read about it and I know that I want to share the DVB adapter with the Internet Connection Sharing on the LAN network.

But when I use the connection sharing, I lose my internet access

I tried to use "Bridge Connection", but then I also lost my internet access too.

Can any one tell me how to fix this problem?

And how to view the channels (for example how to use the VLC)?

Answer (score 1):

You go the wrong way. You need a tv server piece of technology like mediaportal, xbmc+for the record, etc. pp. Especially you need a multiseat setup that is a tv server on your computer with dvb card and a client technology on your other computer. Unfortunately I have only experience with a single seat (tv server and client on the same computer) but I can recommend you mediaportal and/or xbmc or the combi xbmc+for the record. They are both free and personally I prefer xbmc+for the record. Xbmc isn't exactly a tv server but you can combine it with mediaportal or for the record. The multiseat setup shouldn't be too complicated when you are familiar with web technology. I hope it helps.